# 'no matching function for call to' dynamic structs?

Tags: c++, function, struct, parameters, dynamic-arrays

Right now I'm trying to dynamically allocate several names into an array of structs using the namePlayers function. However when I try to compile I get this error:

`|39|error: no matching function for call to 'namePlayers'`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

struct Game{
    string name;
    int position;
};

void namePlayers(Game *player[], int &numberOfPlayers);
/*void play(int &size, int &player1, int &player2, int cardPile[], int board[]);
void displayRules();
int takeTurn(int &size, int &player, int cardPile[], int board[], int &opposingPlayer);
int shuffleDeck(int &size, int cardPile[]);
int switchPlaces(int &player, int &opposingPlayer);
int obstacles(int &player, int board[]);
void showState(int &player1, int &player2);
int reshuffle(int &size, int cardPile[]);
void youWin(int &player1, int &player2);*/

int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    int board[] = {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int cardPile[10] = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 5};
    int numberOfPlayers = 0;
    int player1 = 0;
    int player2 = 0;

    Game *player = new Game[numberOfPlayers];

    namePlayers(player, numberOfPlayers);

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++){
        cout << player[i].name << endl;
    }

    //play(size, player1, player2, cardPile, board);

    return 0;
}

void namePlayers(Game *player[], int &numberOfPlayers){
    cout << "How many players are playing(up to 6)?" << endl;
    cin >> numberOfPlayers;

     for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++){
        cout << "Enter your name:";
        cin >> (*player[i]).name;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++){
        cout << (*player[i]).name << endl;
    }

}


/*//This is the function that plays the entire game
void play(int &size, int &player1, int &player2, int cardPile[], int board[]){
    displayRules();
    shuffleDeck(size, cardPile);
    while(player1 < 25 && player2 < 25){
            cout << "\nPlayer 1's turn!" << endl;
            takeTurn(size, player1, cardPile, board, player2);
            size++;
            reshuffle(size, cardPile);
            showState(player1, player2);
                if(player1 >= 25)
                    break;
                else
                    cout << "\nPlayer 2's turn!" << endl,
                    takeTurn(size, player2, cardPile, board, player1),
                    size++,
                    reshuffle(size, cardPile);
                    showState(player1, player2);
    }

    youWin(player1, player2);

}


//This function displays the rules of the game
void displayRules(){
    cout << "\nWelcome to GoHome! The main objective of this game is to reach Home"
            " first." << endl;
    cout << "The basic rules of the game are as follows:" << endl;
    cout << "\n-To begin the player with the shortest name goes first." << endl;
    cout << "-Each player picks a card that has a number on it and the player"
            " must moves forward that many number of spaces." << endl;
    cout << "-If a card says 'Lose A Turn', the player does nothing and the"
            "turn moves to the next player." << endl;
    cout << "-If a card says 'Switch Places', that player is allowed to switch"
            " places with any player on the board." << endl;
    cout << "-If a player lands on an obstacle, that player must move back that"
            " many number of spaces." << endl;
    cout << "-If a player lands another obstacle while moving backwards, then it"
            " does not have to move backwards again.\n"<<endl;
}


//This function does a single turn for each player
int takeTurn(int &size, int &player, int cardPile[], int board[],int &opposingPlayer){
    if(cardPile[size] == 0)
        cout << "You drew a Lose a turn card! You lose a turn!" << endl;

    else if(cardPile[size] == 5)
        cout << "You drew a Switch Places card! You must switch places with the"
                " other player!" << endl,
        switchPlaces(player, opposingPlayer);

    else
    cout << "You drew a " << cardPile[size] << "!";
        switch(cardPile[size]){
        case 1:
            cout << " Move forward " << cardPile[size] << " space on the board!" << endl;
            player += cardPile[size];
            obstacles(player, board);
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << " Move forward " << cardPile[size] << " spaces on the board!" << endl;
            player += cardPile[size];
            obstacles(player, board);
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << " Move forward " << cardPile[size] << " spaces on the board!" << endl;
            player += cardPile[size];
            obstacles(player, board);
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << " Move forward " << cardPile[size] << " spaces on the board!" << endl;
            player += cardPile[size];
            obstacles(player, board);
            break;
        }
}


//This function shuffles the deck of cards
int shuffleDeck(int &size, int cardPile[]){
    srand(time(0));
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            int size = rand() % 10;
            int temp = cardPile[i];
            cardPile[i] = cardPile[size];
            cardPile[size] = temp;
    }

}


//This function forces player 1 and player 2 to switch places
int switchPlaces(int &player, int &opposingPlayer){
    int temp = player;
    player = opposingPlayer;
    opposingPlayer = temp;
}


//This is the function that tells a player when they have ran into an
//obstacle and moves them back the appropriate number of spaces
int obstacles(int &player, int board[]){
    if(player == 1)
        player -= board[1],
        cout << "You ran into an obstacle! Move back 1 space!" << endl;
    else if(player == 4)
        player -= board[4],
        cout << "You ran into an obstacle! Move back 1 space!" << endl;
    else if(player == 8)
        player -= board[8],
        cout << "You ran into an obstacle! Move back 2 spaces!" << endl;
    else if(player == 12)
        player -= board[12],
        cout << "You ran into an obstacle! Move back 3 spaces!" << endl;
    else if(player == 16)
        player -= board[16],
        cout << "You ran into an obstacle! Move back 2 spaces!" << endl;
    else if(player == 20)
        player -= board[20],
        cout << "You ran into an obstacle! Move back 1 space!" << endl;

return player;

}


//This function shows what spot on the board both players are on
void showState(int &player1, int &player2){

    if(player1 == 0)
        cout << "\nPlayer 1 is at Start!" <<endl;
    else
        cout << "\nPlayer 1 is on spot " << player1 << " of the board." <<endl;


    if(player2 == 0)
        cout << "Player 2 is at Start!\n" <<endl;
    else
        cout << "Player 2 is on spot " << player2 << " of the board.\n" <<endl;

}


//This function looks to see if the pile of cards has run out
//and call for the shuffle function to reshuffle the deck
int reshuffle(int &size, int cardPile[]){
    if(size == 10)
        shuffleDeck(size, cardPile),
        size = 0;
    else
        ;
}


//This function displays a message saying who won the game
void youWin(int &player1, int &player2){
        if(player1 >= 25)
            cout << "\nWinner! Player 1 reached Home first!\n" << endl;
        else
            cout << "\nWinner! Player 2 reached Home first!\n" << endl;

}*/
```

EDIT: Here is the entire code. I commented out the parts I'm not currently working on. I have to use dynamic allocation because it's a part of the assignment.

Comment: Any special reason you can't post _all_ the code, including the #includes?

Comment: `numberOfPlayers` is uninitialised when you allocate the array. You need to first ask for the number of players, then create the array, then input the players' names. If you want to restrict the number to a maximum of six, you don't need dynamic allocation at all.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of `namePlayers` is of type `Game *[]`, but you're passing in a `Game *`. Based on usage, I'm assuming you want to change the function to accept a `Game *` and remove the extra dereferences in the function body itself.

Answer (score 0):

The program does not make sense.

for example  in this code snippet in main the variable `numberOfPlayers` has indeterminate value because it is uninitialized.

```
int numberOfPlayers;

Game *player = new Game[numberOfPlayers];
```

By this reason the program already has undefined behavior.

Further the first function parameter

```
void namePlayers(Game *player[], int &numberOfPlayers);
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

has type `Game **` while it is called with the argument having the type `Game *`.

```
namePlayers(player, numberOfPlayers);
            ^^^^^^
```

It would be better to declare the second parameter as having type `size_t` instead of the type `int`. Otherwise the user can enter a negative number and again the program will have undefined behavior.

I would declare and define the function the following way

```
Game * namePlayers( size_t &numberOfPlayers )
{
    Game *player = nullptr;
    numberOfPlayers = 0;

    cout << "How many players are playing(up to 6)?" << endl;
    cin >> numberOfPlayers;


    if ( numberOfPlayers )
    {
        player = new Game[numberOfPlayers];

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++ )
        {
            cout << "Enter your name:";
            cin >> player[i].name;
        }
    }

    return player;
}
```

And in main the code could look like

```
size_t numberOfPlayers;

Game *player = namePlayers( numberOfPlayers );

for ( size_t i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++ )
{
    cout << player[i].name << endl;
}

//...
delete [] player;
```

**EDIT:**

After you changed the code in your question nevertheless this allocation does not make sense.

```
int numberOfPlayers = 0;
//...
Game *player = new Game[numberOfPlayers];
```